# ArcGIS 9.3. for Silverlight Missing color swatch inside legend

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, legend, arcgis-silverlight-api

I have an ArcGIS 9.3. MapService and a Silverlight Application that consumes it. The application is deployed on two diffrent Systems. On system A everything is fine. On system B the map service is displayed correctly, as well as the legend for it. But what is missing are the color swatches inside the legend. I can see that the color swatch images are created inside the arcgisoutput folder. And I can access them via the web browser. When I debug the application of system B with fiddler, I see that there are no request trying to get the swatch images, as it is the case for system A.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I have just noticed that in the response of the getLegendInfo Request the ImageURL containes the machine name instead of the ip adress of the gisserver. How can I configure the url?